# How to group by every column except a chosen column(s)?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I often find myself having a long list on column numbers when I call a GROUP BY function like below:

```
SELECT
Field1
,Field2
,Field3
,Field4
,Field5
,Field6
,Field7
,Field8
,Field9
,Field10
,Field11
,Field12
,max(field13)
FROM Data
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

Is there any way for me to simplify this and just state the columns that I would not like to group by? So instead of the above it would look something like this:

```
SELECT
Field1
,Field2
,Field3
,Field4
,Field5
,Field6
,Field7
,Field8
,Field9
,Field10
,Field11
,Field12
,max(field13)
FROM Data
GROUP BY NOT 13
```

It's a minor annoyance having to type out all the individual numbers so it would be pretty convenient if I could simplify it somehow!

Comment: Note that `SELECT *` is generally incompatible with `GROUP BY`.  I suggest including the actual select clauses.

Comment: give more precise example because the above SQL script is not logical
Why use GROUP BY in a simple SELECT?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I have added a clearer explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select any_value((select as struct * except(Field13) from unnest([t]))).*,
  max(field13)
from your_table t
group by to_json_string((select as struct * except(Field13) from unnest([t])))
```

if it looks little verbose/redundant - use below version of same

```
select any_value(cols).*, max(Field13)
from (
    select (select as struct * except(Field13) from unnest([t])) cols, Field13
    from your_table t
)
group by to_json_string(cols)
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! You've finally managed to scratch an itch I've been trying to solve for months!